# Change system time using any language

Tags: systemtime

I want to change system time on window os but i don't want to use kernel32.dll because my os will write an log entry @@

Pls help me.

Comment: [`SetSystemTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx) is the only way to change the system time. But you say you don't want to use that function?

Comment: I don't want to import kernel32.dll to my project. Other way to solve my problem ?

Comment: Your concern is somehow misguided. `kernel32.dll` is *always* part of every Win32 program. Without that, you can do nothing useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can try using the [win32api.SetSystemTime](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetSystemTime_meth.html). That is part of [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/)

Comment: Thank you Frankline.

win32api.SetSystemTime

int = SetSystemTime(year, month , dayOfWeek , day , hour , minute , second , millseconds )
But i don't khow how to import this code to my project with c# language. Help me !!!